# How to deploy ASP.NET service and client on iis server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

i have WCF project with client and service side and i'm trying to deploy it on IIS service. i saw a lot of tutorials and video on how to do that but all that is different from my code. in the service code [image]

DPL.Service.Host work with FACADE,DAL,COMMON AND BL and have all the references i dont have there a .svc file but i read that it possible to write it like new

```
ServiceHost( typeof( MyNamespace.MyServiceImplementationTypeName ) )
```

and thats acctualy how the service is written the code is:

```
using DPL.Server.BL;
using DPL.Server.Common.Providers;
using DPL.Server.Facade;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DPL.Server.Host
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null; 

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (null != myServiceHost)
                {
                    myServiceHost.Close();
                }
                LogFileProvider.WriteLine("Service Started");

                myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(DPLService));
                myServiceHost.Open();
                LogFileProvider.WriteLine("Run Core.StartBL()");
                Core.StartBL();

                LogFileProvider.WriteLine("Service OnStart Done!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogFileProvider.WriteException(99, "OnStart", e);
                throw;
            }         
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (null != myServiceHost)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i have configuration file app.config that im not acctualy sure if it is good for the IIS server to run on localhost. the code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- ____________________________________________________________ Data Base Connection _____________________________________________________________________ -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="DPL.Server.Facade.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

    <!--<add name="DPL_SqlServer" connectionString="server='PROSQL01'                           ;database=Dpl                           ;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->

    <add name="DPL_SqlServer" connectionString="server='(local)\SQLEXPRESS'&#xD;&#xA;                          ;database=Dpl&#xD;&#xA;                          ;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

                                                      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- ____________________________________________________________ WCF Configuration _____________________________________________________________________ -->
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DPL.Server.Facade.DPLService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="DPL.Server.Facade.IDPLService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8722/DPLService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <userSettings>
    <DPL.Server.Facade.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="UseMockBl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
    </DPL.Server.Facade.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

ill be very happy if someone can help me to figure that out

p.s i run win server 2016 in virtual box and downloaded IIS server there

thanks

Andrey

Comment: you want to deploy Windows Service in IIS? use InstallUtil for installing the Windows Service

Comment: @AkshayJoy i run win server 2016 in virtual box and download the IIS server... and about the installUtill i did that but cant run the service with net start access is denied even in administrator mode

Comment: can you please update the screenshot for the InstallUtil Error? so that I can help you with this, P

Comment: typically when you self-host you loose all of the APP Pool handling, Exception handling and recovery facilities provided by IIS. You could re-use the same code-base by refactoring out the WCF Service aspects and make a web app which references the library. After which you can host both in IIS and self-host using Windows Services